# How to see stories on a Kanban board before they are in a sprint in Jira?

Tags: jira, kanban, scrumboard

I moved from DevOps to Jira, and I'm surprised that all stories and tasks and everything are just tangled in the backlog outside my sprint. I want to use a Kanban to sort my stories into the following categories:

- Ideas
- Validated
- Ready to be done
- Being done in an actual sprint
- Done

And then, I would like to have another Kanban board for the sprint where I only see the things "being done in the actual sprint," and I move them to like to do-in progress-done

**Is there a way to have a Kanban board in JIRA for stories that are NOT in my sprint yet?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, easy answer is to create 2 projects, one Kanban Software Development, the other as Scrum Software Development. Move tasks that are in progress to the Scrum Software Development project. Leave the ideas in the Kanban Software Development Project. You can also customize the issue types in the Jira settings if you want to use 1 project, or add a Kanban board to a Scrum Project to create a hybrid. You can apply filters to the Kanban board to only show certain workflow options.

Comment: worked like a charm. Added a Kanban where only stories and bugs can be seen and I use Epics as swimlanes. In the Scrum board I only see subtasks using stories as swimlines. 
Now my only problem is that movement of subtasks and their parent stories is NOT synchroniced. All subtasks can be done and the story is still in process :( Any clue ?

Comment: I’ve never done that, but ScriptRunner, or maybe the REST API would be useful there if it’s not a standard option, then run it in a scheduled job every “x” minutes if you need that. It might not be worth doing to save 1 or 2 clicks. I think it’s always good for a lead to verify the story before closing, and for the story task itself to be assigned to a lead. Sometimes holding them accountable is better than automation. Or maybe even integrate the closure of the story after a pull request is approved and that code is officially in the master branch.

Comment: automating to pull request would be perfect but we don't have integration between jira and t he code base.. at all :( The solution i've read about would be to use a plugin called jira automation lite. Which is free and seams to be capable of doing those things. As for the accountability I totally agree and the thing is that we set accountability at subtask level and, furthermore, the "coded" status where sub-tasks die is not the "Done" for the story so still we need someone to deal with the Story. But I want to automate the notification that all sub-tasks are done..